# Configuring Microsoft R server on computer with Swedish Windows

Tags: r, powershell, configuration, server, microsoft-r

After installing Microsoft R Server 9.1.0 on my computer I follow the guide published on Microsofts docs to configure it with the One Box configuration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/install/operationalize-r-server-one-box-config

However when the Admin utility runs the Powershell script file to configure the Compute Node (o16n_computenode_config.ps1) it runs into this exception:

> "Exception calling "SetOwner" with "1" argument(s): "En eller flera >identitetsreferenser blev inte (a distorted symbol instead of the proper >Swedish character)versatt."
>   At C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R >Server\R_SERVER\o16n\o16n_computenode_config.ps1:343 char:5"

And also:

> "Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "En eller flera >identitetsreferenser blev inte (a distorted symbol instead of the proper >Swedish character)versatt."
>   At C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R >Server\R_SERVER\o16n\o16n_computenode_config.ps1:357 char:9"

After looking into the specific lines in the .ps1 file it looks to me that the exceptions happen when the process is trying to access the builtin\administrators users and find the standard admin account which on a Swedish Windows have a non-English character in it which we believe causes the exception.

The code lines in question:

```
#set Administrator as owner
$ID = new-object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($Admins)
$acl.SetOwner($ID) >> $logFile
```

And

```
if ((Get-Item $dir) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo])
    {
        $rule = New-Object 
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$Admins","FullControl", 
"ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow") 
    }
    else
    {
        $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$Admins","FullControl",,,"Allow") 
    }
    try
    {
        $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    }
```

So my question pretty much boils down to this.
Has anyone else run into this problem? Is the exception caused, as we believe, by the non-English character or could it be something else? Is it there a workaround to make it work?

Comment: Could you not just temporarily rename the admin account to remove the non-standard characters?

Comment: I agree with @MarkWragg; rename the admin account.

Comment: @MarkWragg I honestly thought that the default accounts on a Windows machine were locked, but if it is possible to change it I will definitely give that a try.

Comment: You definitely can rename the default admin account and it's often encouraged from a security perspective.

Comment: I pinged the MRS team about this. Proper internationalisation is in the backlog; in the meantime, the recommended workaround is to rename the Admin account as @MarkWragg said.

Comment: @MarkWragg
Sadly just changing the account name did not fix the issue. But I imagine there might be a path or a user group or something similar that is referenced that uses a non-English character.

Comment: @HongOoi
That is good to hear. :) What channels did you use to get into contact with the team?